# Javascript delay event

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I have a function `handleScroll` which needs to be called when the window's scroll position changes. Here is the code for that

```
$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```

But the problem is that above code ends up calling `handleScroll` too frequently. How can I modify the above code so that handleScroll is only called after the user has stopped scrolling for 200 milliseconds?

Comment: This is called ["debouncing"](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timeoutHandle;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (timeoutHandle) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    }
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
        handleScroll(e);
        timeoutHandle = null;
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) library, it can be easy as

```
var debounceid = _.debounce(handleScroll, 200);
$(window).resize(debounceid);
```